# Display JS Calculation Sum In An Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the sum of this calculation in an input field:

```
function calculateSum1() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $("input.miles").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("input.summiles").value(sum);
}
```

input field:

```
<input class="summiles" type="text" value="">
```

It works fine if I display it in a span, but I can't seem to get it to display in an input field.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** instead of `value()` to set the textbox.

```
 $("input.summiles").val(sum);
```

Comment: Man, I knew it was something simple... Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

.vale is the raw javascript attribute, while .val is the jquery function so you have to change:

```
     $("input.summiles").value(sum);
```

to either:

```
     $("input.summiles").value=sum;
```

or

```
     $("input.summiles").val(sum);
```

These are identical and there are no efficiency tradeoffs as .val() is a very thin wrapper around value. As you are already using jQuery, I would recommend standardizing under "one framework", and using .val()

Comment: Thanks for the alternative and the lesson!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$("input.summiles").value(sum);
```

to

```
$("input.summiles").val(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate jQuery function is `.val()`, not `.value()`. Don't ask why.

Comment: well why its appropriate ?:P

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$("input.summiles").value(sum);
```

to

```
$("input.summiles").val(sum);
```

jQuery has no `.value()` function.